# AngularJS RESTful POST response

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm new to AngularJS. I have a simple java RESTful service that return a json.
And a function in a Collector:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $resource) {

$scope.mapp_login_email = '';
$scope.mapp_login_password='';  
$scope.loginAPI = function() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
    $scope.loginAPI = $resource(baseUrl + '/api/login/post', {}, {
        login2: {method: 'POST'}
    });        
    var response = $scope.loginAPI.login2({ email: $scope.mapp_login_email, password: $scope.mapp_login_password });

    response.$promise.then(function(value) {        
        var data = JSON.stringify(value, ['returnCode', 'errMsg']); 
        $scope.mapp_login_email = data.returnCode;
    });     

  }
```

});

The RESTful service is being called and I see in the network tab that it returns a json response:

```
{returnCode: "OK", status: 0, errMsg: null}
```

How can I evaluated in the angularJS code the return value from the RESTful service?

Thanks,
Ronen

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way to use HTTP with angular. Try the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
$http
.post(baseUrl + '/api/login/post', null, { 
    email: $scope.mapp_login_email, 
    password: $scope.mapp_login_password 
})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    // on success
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // on error
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle promise in then clause

```
response.$promise.then(function(value) {
    $scope.data = value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this way I got the following value: [object Object]

Comment: Now you can do JSON.stringify to check the values.

Comment: Thanks. JSON.stringify returns the json string. In my case it's: "{returnCode: "OK", status: 0, errMsg: null}". How can I check the value of returnCode only? Thanks, Ronen

Comment: To check returnCode you can do  
e.g.

 `var data = {returnCode: "OK", status: 0, errMsg: null}` 
And then you can access returnCode like below.
`data.returnCode`

https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/e84dotc5/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new with Angular and JS and therefore I struggle with this. I really appreciate your help!
Following last comment, data.returnCode is empty. I updated the code I'm running in the original question. As I understand, I'm getting a json back from the server. In the network tab from the browser I see that I get the following response: {"returnCode":"BAD","status":-1,"errMsg":null}
I want to evaluate the returnCode and to display the errMsg if exist. 
Why do I need to use JSON.stringify?

Comment: Ok, what value you are getting now. If its `{returnCode: "OK", status: 0, errMsg: null}` then you can just follow jsfiddle i provided above and you will good to go :)

Comment: For some reason the value in data.returnCode is empty in my app. I'll continue to check. Thanks, Ronen